# How to post to a MS-teams webhook from Esp8266?

Tags: arduino, iot, webhooks, esp8266

I have an ESP8266 and want to send messages to a MS-Teams channel. In the future I want to send temperature data but for now I am okay with whatever.
Right now I can connect to the host but it will not send any data to the team and it gives no error.
It works without any problems from Postman and the webhook also works from Python.

Here is my code:

```
#include "ESP8266HTTPClient.h"
#include "ESP8266WiFi.h"
#include <ArduinoJson.h>
#include <WiFiClientSecure.h>

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);                                  //Serial connection
  WiFi.begin("", ""); //WiFi connection
  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) { //Wait for the WiFI connection completion 
    delay(500);
    Serial.println("Waiting for connection");
  }
}

void MicrosoftTeams() {
  char host[] = "outlook.office.com"; //Specify request destination";
  WiFiClient client;
  if (client.connect(host, 443)) {
    Serial.println("connected");

    String url = "/webhook/Webhookcode";
    char json[] = "{  \"@context\": 
 \"https://schema.org/extensions\",\"@type\": 
 \"MessageCard\",\"themeColor\": \"0072C6\",\"title\": 
 \"meddelande\",\"text\": \"Hello!!\"}";
    int len = strlen(json);

    String Output = "POST " + url + " HTTP/1.1\r\n" +
                    "Host: " + host + "\r\n" +
                    "Content-Type: application/json\r\n" +
                    "User-Agent: arduino/1.0\r\n" +
                    "Content-Length: " + len + "\r\n" +
                    "\r\n" +
                    json + "\n";

    client.print(Output);
    while (client.available()) {
      String line = client.readStringUntil('\r');
      Serial.print(line);
    }
  }
}

void loop() {
  if (WiFi.status() == WL_CONNECTED) { //Check WiFi connection status
    MicrosoftTeams();
  } else {
    Serial.println("Error in WiFi connection");
  }
  delay(30000); //Send a request every 30 seconds
}
```

**Update:**
Ive tested the following function and it works in this test example but not the real case. If i change the WiFiClient to WiFiClientSecure everything stops working.

```
void WifiCliwaySecure()
{
  //Work
      WiFiClient  client;
  const int httpPort = 80;
  // //Doenst work
  //   WiFiClientSecure  client;
  // const int httpPort = 443;
  char host[] = "ptsv2.com";
  if (!client.connect(host, httpPort)) {
    Serial.println("connection failed");
    return;
  }

    String url = "/t/erzs7-1555484154/post";
   Serial.print("Requesting POST: ");
   // Send request to the server:
 String data = "{ \"title\": \"meddelande\",\"text\": \"Hallå alla bk!!\"}";
  client.print(String("POST ") + url + " HTTP/1.1\r\n" +
               "Host: " + host + "\r\n" +
               "User-Agent: BuildFailureDetectorESP8266\r\n" +
               "Content-Length: " + data.length() + "\r\n" +
               "Content-Type: application/json\r\n" +
               "\r\n" + 
               data +
               "\r\n");
Serial.print("url Send");

   delay(500); // Can be changed
  if (client.connected()) { 
    client.stop();  // DISCONNECT FROM THE SERVER
  }
  Serial.println();
  Serial.println("closing connection");
}
```

Comment: Are you able to prove that this code works for a simpler case? For example over HTTP instead of HTTPS? As a way of narrowing down exactly where the problem lies?

Comment: I'm also pretty certain that you should be using WiFiClientSecure instead of WiFiClient. Beware that HTTPS may need more RAM than is available and for this reason can cause your ESP8266 to freeze or reboot unexpectedly.

Comment: @phil i updated the code, 
The problem to the test is that if the port is 443 or the client is WiFiClientSecure it doesnt work. Se the updated part.

Comment: WifiClient works when you connect to remote port 80 because it is HTTP and therefore not encrypted. It won't work when you connect to remote port 443 because it is HTTPS (encrypted), which WifiClient doesn't support. I'll add an answer in the next couple of days showing you how to get your WifiClientSecure version working.

Answer (score 1):

By 2021, you should do the following:

```C
#include <WiFi.h>
#include <HTTPClient.h>

void notifyTeams() {
  // === Check WiFi connection status
  if (WiFi.status()== WL_CONNECTED) {
  
   HTTPClient http;   

   // == The incoming webhooks as given by Microsoft Teams
   String url = "https://XXXXX.webhook.office.com/webhookb2/YYYYY/IncomingWebhook/ZZZZ/AAAA";
  
   http.begin(url);  
   http.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json"); 

   // Send request to the server:
   String data = "{ \"title\": \"Slug’s here!\", \"text\": \"Quickly go catch her!\"}";

   int httpResponseCode = http.POST(data);
  
   if(httpResponseCode>0) {
  
    // === Get the response to the request
    String response = http.getString();                       
  
    Serial.println(httpResponseCode);   
    Serial.println(response);          
  
   }
   else {
  
    Serial.print("Error on sending POST: ");
    Serial.println(httpResponseCode);
  
   }
  
   http.end(); 
 } 
 else {
  
    Serial.println("Error in WiFi connection");   
  
 }
}
```